# problem with starting a new powershell instance and delete folder

Tags: powershell

i have the problem, that i need to start a powershell script A, which starts a new instance of powershell with admin rights and deletes the entire folder where script A is inside

```
invoke-expression 'cmd /c start powershell -Verb RunAs -Command { remove-item -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\testfolder"}'
```

this doesn't work for me. how can i achieve that?

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "doesn't work for me" - are you having a bad day and "just not feeling it", or did an error or unexpected behavior occur? If so, please share the error message or describe the unexpected behavior :-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't get any error message. The problem is, that the folder is still there after running my code above.

Comment: Alright, try changing `cmd /c` to `cmd /k` - this will cause `cmd` to keep open after executing the command, perhaps you'll be able to observe any error

Comment: Unfortunately still no error message. I think it depends on the second powershell instatnce. i can start the instance as admin

Answer (score 0):

After the script has finished running, look at the `$error` variable, all errors in the powershell session are stored in the `$error variable. As long as the window has not closed, you can look at the $error variable.

Comment: there is still no error message. if i delete the -Verb RunAs argument, it says i have no rights -> at the end, this is true. if i put it back, i need to confirm that i am admin. maybe the -Verb RunAs is wrong?

Comment: Open PowerShell ISE,  and then run your command, `start powershell -Verb RunAs -Command {remove-item -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\testfolder"}` and then check if the command is successfull, and check the `$error` variable also. At least you know if your command works first